# Where do the power leads attach to this simple sound circuit?

Tags: power

This is a really simple circuit that goes to a speaker in a clock that my friend wants fixed.
The power lead broke off.
I just need to know where the positive power lead gets attached.
It is powered with 2 AA batteries.

The pair of yellow wires attach to a button, presumably for testing.

The pair of black wires go into the clock, presumably to be switched on when the hour strikes.

The pair of red wires goes to the speaker.

The epoxy blob appears to just be a stand-off so that the circuit doesn't hit the bottom of the enclosing box.

No idea what tags to use on this question.  Please edit :)

[image: Side A]

[image: Side B]

Comment: Since the negative power lead appears to be soldered onto the bottom instead of going through a hole, look for a solder blob that has a broken-off bit of wire coming out of it.  It appears this may be the case for the topmost lead of R1 in your top photograph -- but you'll have to look yourself to make sure.

Comment: The epoxy blob is not a standoff. It's there to protect the bare silicon die stuck to the PCB - it's the IC which makes the sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tracing the circuit suggest that it connects to top of R1 or the C1 terminal nearest the corner. both are the same circuit node so pick whichever is most convenient.